# How do you highlight all roads within a selected scale on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

[My grandparents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759) will drive through back roads in rurality (hereafter call these BR), but my grandparents' ignorance of (the availability or location) of these BR precludes them from zooming in sufficiently to cause the map to  reveal the small roads. It is too inefficient and unreliable to zoom in and manually scroll through large areas, to try to detect these BR yourself. E.g.:

For a first look, a scale would be chosen to see the entirety of an area (e.g. of [Parc national du Mont-Tremblant](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.3832771,-74.3281375,10z?hl=en), Québec, Canada); but it fails to reveal the BR  within the red circles that I added:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you need to use the "Draw along roads" tool in My Maps.

[> Reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/Hi3mc1W3X7g)